# KubernetesPodOperator is not able to access the Airflow Connections stored in Google Secrets Manager

Tags: kubernetes-pod, google-cloud-composer, kubernetes-secrets, kubernetespodoperator, airflow-connections

I am using the `Composer version 2.0.0 Airflow 2.1.4` and I have created a `KubernetesPodOperator` that is trying to access the Airflow connection stored in the Google Secrets Manager. But it isn't able to locate the credentials (check exceptions below). I have also tried to pass the airflow connection secrets to `env_vars` in `KubernetesPodOperator` and also tried to pass it as `Kubernetes Secrets` to the pod but still no luck.

Below is my code for both the cases above:

```
aws_uri = BaseHook.get_connection('aws_conn').get_uri()

download_file = KubernetesPodOperator(
        task_id="download_file_s3_to_gcs",
        dag=dag,
        name="download_file_s3_to_gcs",
        namespace=NAMESPACE,
        in_cluster=True,
        image=IMAGE_NAME,
        arguments=[
            "python3",
            "%s" % FILENAME,
        ],
        service_account_name=K_SERVICE_ACCOUNT,
        env_vars=[k8s.V1EnvVar(name="gcp_conn_id", value=GCP_CONN_ID), k8s.V1EnvVar(name="aws_conn_id", value=aws_uri)],
        is_delete_operator_pod=True,
    )
```

```
secret_aws_conn_id = Secret(
        deploy_type='env',
        deploy_target='AWS_CONN_ID',
        secret='aws-conn-id', // my kubernetes secret
        key='aws-conn-key',
    )

download_file = KubernetesPodOperator(
        task_id="download_file_s3_to_gcs",
        dag=dag,
        name="download_file_s3_to_gcs",
        namespace=NAMESPACE,
        in_cluster=True,
        image=IMAGE_NAME,
        arguments=[
            "python3",
            "%s" % FILENAME,
        ],
        service_account_name=K_SERVICE_ACCOUNT,
        secrets=[secret_aws_conn_id],
        env_vars=[k8s.V1EnvVar(name="gcp_conn_id", value=GCP_CONN_ID)],
        is_delete_operator_pod=True,
    )
```

Although, when i print the `connection_id` URI i can get the URI for it correctly but the job always throw below exceptions

```
[2022-04-01 08:01:09,563] {pod_manager.py:197} INFO - botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials

[2022-04-01 08:01:09,374] {pod_manager.py:197} INFO - sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: connection
[2022-04-01 08:01:09,375] {pod_manager.py:197} INFO - [SQL: SELECT connection.password AS connection_password, connection.extra AS connection_extra, connection.id AS connection_id, connection.conn_id AS connection_conn_id, connection.conn_type AS connection_conn_type, connection.description AS connection_description, connection.host AS connection_host, connection.schema AS connection_schema, connection.login AS connection_login, connection.port AS connection_port, connection.is_encrypted AS connection_is_encrypted, connection.is_extra_encrypted AS connection_is_extra_encrypted
[2022-04-01 08:01:09,375] {pod_manager.py:197} INFO - FROM connection
[2022-04-01 08:01:09,376] {pod_manager.py:197} INFO - WHERE connection.conn_id = ?
[2022-04-01 08:01:09,376] {pod_manager.py:197} INFO -  LIMIT ? OFFSET ?]

[2022-04-01 08:01:09,354] {pod_manager.py:197} INFO - [[34m2022-04-01 08:01:09,297[0m] {[34mconnection.py:[0m407} ERROR[0m - Unable to retrieve connection from secrets backend (MetastoreBackend). 
Checking subsequent secrets backend.[0m
```

Can someone please help me out to resolve this issue?

Comment: Is your issue resolved?

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass Airflow connections from Airflow to the pod directly.

The error log shows that you have Airflow operator code running inside the Pod. This code will call secret manager/Airflow metadata database to retrieve credentials based on connection ID. As you can see from the log, Pod can't reach metadata database.

I would recommend to pass GCP credentials as a Kubernetes secret and use GCS python client inside the container. The container itself should not be dependent on Airflow - Airflow only schedules it.

Comment: spot on. Can you explain in short how to create this secret and have K8sOp access it?

Comment: Connect to K8 cluster with kubectl CLI and create secret with "kubectl create secret" command. Afterwards in the DAG, create Secret object as specified in the article below and pass it to K8sOp. https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-cncf-kubernetes/stable/operators.html#how-to-use-cluster-configmaps-secrets-and-volumes-with-pod